# Нужно ли ставить запятую? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Проблема в том, что старики зачастую остаются одни(?) без поддержки близких.*
Нужна ли запятая в указанном месте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разный смысл.

Смотрите (маленькая рокировочка):

*без поддержки близких старики зачастую остаются одни* - всё на месте, можно жить без запятой, акцент на беспомощности;

а с запятой - уточнение к одиночеству (а именно).

Так что читабельны оба варианта:

*Проблема в том, что старики зачастую остаются одни без поддержки близких. / Проблема в том, что старики зачастую остаются одни, без поддержки близких.*